# Broken dependencies while installing redmine using apt on fresh 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mysql, ruby, redmine

On vanilla 14.04:

1. run aptitude
2. chose package redmine
3. see broken conflicting package problem (something with ruby-rack)

How can I deal with it?

Comment: Please, post the full output of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep package_name
```

or if you have synaptic, there is a filter for broken packages that you can see and then fix.